# Multilanguage in VB.net programm

Tags: vb.net, size, translation, multilingual

im the first time confronted with a task for a multilanguaged program.
The project is already existing in one language but it should have a multilanguage support.

Is it recommended to use a **complete new project for each language or** should i go with **language files** which would make the translation works easier?
For translations there are often hired translators from outside the project and you propably dont want to give them access to the source code directly to translate so a file based solution would spare much time.

The other problem which could come up is the different **length of the words** in different languages for labels of buttons for example. It shouldn't get cutted or resizing the buttons/labels too much. Is there an easy **possibility to adjust the text size based on the length?** Or should i go with a custom function which calculates the text size depending on width and word length?

For example the English word "Save":
English: Save (4), Spain: Ahorrar (7), German: Speichern (9), French: Enregistrer (11)

Comment: You should look into globalization and localization. The former is enabling support for multiple languages in your app and the latter is adding support for a specific language. Basically, all the text that might change is stored in resources with the resources for your default language built into the application itself. You then add a DLL with specific properties for each additional language you want to support, with all the resources for that language.

Comment: If you want to display all text in all languages without resizing controls then you have to either make the controls big enough for the longest text or else write your own code to change font sizes on a case by case basis. It's up to you to test the app in each language to make sure that it looks the way you want it to.

Comment: Re text length, there are rules of thumb for "design" physical width vs. width of text in English, but they don't always hold, e.g. I've had 25% extra suggested for some of my work, but Russian strings tend to run longer than that.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you very much for your answers. So i should use the integrated localisation tool if i understood right, is there a good way to let translators work on the translation without giving them access to the whole source project?

Comment: You should be able to pass resource files (.resx extensio) to the translators.  They're XML, and the part that has the language-specific strings is really easy to work with: the format is `<data name="{resource name}"><value>{resource text}</value></data>`.  They would return the language-appropriate version of the file, e.g. resources.ru-RU.resx would be the Russian version of resources.resx.

Comment: In a VB project, by default, the resources end up in a Resources.resx file located in the My Project folder.  I don't remember how practical it is to spread resources out into multiple files in VB, as the projects that I work on that have multiple string resource files are all in C#.

Comment: @Craig Thanks a lot. I will check that out.